# Scala's Range with Float performance does not meet expectations

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I typed the code below in scala console and get the return:

```
scala> 1.0F to 5.0F by 1.3F
res10: scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Float] = NumericRange(1.0, 2.3, 3.6, 4.8999996)
```

why the ret is `NumericRange(1.0, 2.3, 3.6, 4.8999996)` instead of `NumericRange(1.0, 2.3, 3.6, 4.9)` ?

Comment: 0.3 in base 10 is a repeating decimal in binary, which gets truncated, and hence you get the difference that you see.

Comment: This comes up over and over again. So much so that there's a website dedicated to it: http://floating-point-gui.de/